# declined Permission handling Facebook Login

Tags: swift, facebook, pfuser

I am trying to force my users to provide their data in order to get access to my app.

Since the syntax in Swift 3 changed a little, I am stuck in developing this. Basically my idea is the following:

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "user_birthday", "user_photos"]

PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions, block:
{ (user, error) -> Void in

            // casting user to FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult
            // asking for specific data declined/granted Permissions
            if let user = user as? FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult {

            print(user.declinedPermissions)
            print(user.grantedPermissions)
        }}
```

My print method will never be called. What is the real way to cast from user(PFUser?) to FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult ?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting back the actual FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult as the result instead of user.

```
 let login:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
 let permissions = ["public_profile", "user_birthday", "user_photos"]
 login.logIn(withReadPermissions: permissions, from: self) { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) -> Void in
   if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil){
       let permissions = FBSDKAccessToken.current().permissions
       print(permissions)
       //Do whatever else you need to do with the result
 }
```

Comment: how can I get now my user from there ? Since I need his details as well